# Libero does synthesis again before programming the device

Tags: microsemi-fpga, libero

I am using a ProASIC3E PQ208 FPGA and Libero tool to write the vhdl code and program the board on which the FPGA is soldered. When I try to open Libero again to program file, it starts the synthesis again. The old synthesis file exists and I have not made any changes, but still there is place and route operation going on everytime I try to program the device .

I have never faced this issue when generating bitstream in Xilinx Vivado. The Actel documentation is also not that great so I could not figure out why this was happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential ways to correct the issue.

1. [Create a script](http://coredocs.s3.amazonaws.com/Libero/2021_1/Tool/pf_tcl_cmd_ref_ug.pdf) that after running all the required steps to generate a config. file (synthesis, place & route, and config. file generation) saves the project
2. Try to program your device by going directly to [Flash Pro](https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/programming-and-debug/4977-flashpro) instead of launching Libero SoC IDE

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am currently using FlashPro to program the device as a workaround. I will try the first option as well, thanks.